# Source of a line about superstitions

Tags: sources-mekorot, superstition

I frequently encounter this line, attributed to Sefer Ḥasidim:

> One should not believe in superstitions, but still it is best to be heedful of them.

Try Googling it and you will get 125 returns.

I could not find it there.  What is the reference?

Comment: How do you know the Sefer Hasidim really says it?

Comment: Look at the very last piece of the Sefer Chassidim and you will see he says the opposite

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Perhaps @sam is referring to this: Siman 1172: אין המזיקים מתגרין אלא במי שמתגרה בהם כגון שכתבו הוא ואבותיו קמיעות או עסקו בכשפים ובהשבעות או בשאלת חלום לכך לא יעסוק אדם בהם ולא יאמר אעשה בשביל פיקוח הפש בהשבעות וקמיע כי אין זה חכמה כי הוא מקצר ימיו וחיי זרעו ואין דוחין נפש מפני נפש ונאמר תמים תהיה ואין לו אלא תפלה ותחנונים על הכל וה' ישמרנו וזרעינו ואת כל אשר לנו מכל רע מעתה ועד עולם אמן ואמן. - the opposite being that there *are* mezikim.

Comment: I read now that there's a second version of Sefer Chassidim that was printed in Berlin in 1891 by [Mekitzei Nirdamim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mekitze_Nirdamim) with about 800 more simanim than the old version. Perhaps it's in there? Here's a l[ink](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=oDY_AAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @Harel13 -- Yes, Siman 1172 seems to be saying the opposite.  Sad to see so many people, even scholars, quote ad infinitum something they never checked.  But perhaps that second source has the line?  Help appreciated.

Comment: @harel13, yes I was referring to that exact piece where he mentions mazikin and he writes to totally ignore them and not heed them .

Answer (score 6):

The original source of the particular formulation of this quote seems to be in the book Jewish Magic and Superstition, by Joshua Trachtenberg, Moshe Idel, [page 23](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Jewish_Magic_and_Superstition/Sy3po8cI0FYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=One%20should%20not%20believe%20in%20superstitions,%20but%20still%20it%20is%20best%20to%20be%20heedful%20of%20them.&pg=PA23&printsec=frontcover):

[image]

They give the reference in Sefer Chassidim in footnote 16, which points to "Sefer Chassidim B 477". Here is the Hebrew text of [the siman](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.477?lang=bi), with the original Hebrew quote in bold:

> שני אחים הנשואים שתי אחיות אחד מהם ימות או לא יצליחו. לכך לא ישאו או יגרש אחד מהם את אשתו אם נעשה הדבר כך וכן שלשה או ארבעה שדרים בבית אחד ששמם אחד לא יצליחו או זרעם. וכן שני חתנים שעושים נשואים בשבת אחת לא יצליחו או ימות האחד. וכן יש זווגים שלא יצליחו או שניהם או אחד מהם אב ובן הנשואים שתי אחיות או אם ובת שני אחים או אדם שהשיא בתו לאחי אשתו. וכן האיש שהוא אלמון ויש לו בן ונשא אלמנה ויש לה בת ומשיא בת אשתו לבנו או בן אשתו לבתו. וכן האדם שלקח אשה ששמה רבקה או שם אחר ובנו לקח אשה ששמה רבקה ובן בנו לקח אשה ששמה רבקה לא יצליחו. תמצא היא לא תצלח שהיא משולשת או הוא משולש שהאדם והבת ובת הבת לקחו ג' שמות נמצא הוא לא יצליח והרבה כיוצא באלה **אע"פ שלא יש לחוש ולא נאמר על זה תמים תהיה.** יש עוד זווגים שלא יצליחו ונפקא מיניה לאיש חסיד למנוע מהם ולחדול כגון ראובן שלקח את רחל ומתה וילדה בנים לראובן ולאחר מותה הניחה בנים לא יקח ראובן את לאה אחותה לפי שאמרו חכמים אחד ממאה אין זוכים להוליד בנים משתי אחיות. אבל אם לא הניחה בנים אם יקח לאה אז יולידו ממנה לפי שהראשונה אחותה לא ילדה לו וכן אם מתה לאדם בתו וילדה לו אשתו בת אחרת אם הראשונה הניחה בן או בת אז תקרא פעם שנית בשם המתה כיון שיש לה זרע ואם אין לה זרע אז לא יקרא השניה בשם המתה ויהיו לו בנים מן השניה כך ענין השער וצריך רחמים גדולים להפוך השער מעניינו. וכן שני אחים אחד נשא אשה אמר לו אחיו עסוק שיתנו לי אחות אשת אחי או בתה או אמה או האב לקח אשה ואמר הבן עסוק שיתנו לי אחותה או בתה כל הירא דבר ה' לא יעסוק בזה. כתיב (תהלים כה יב) מי האיש ירא השם יורנו בדרך יבחר וכתיב (קהלת ט ד) כי מי אשר יחבר אל כל החיים יש בטחון יחבר קרי יבחר כתיב כיון שאמרו לשלישי לא תנשא או לרביעי מר כדאית ליה ומר כדאית ליה אם עבר ונשא אשה שבעליה מתו הרי עתיד ליתן הדין שהוא מסתכן בעצמו. דכתיב (בראשית ט ה) ואך את דמכם לנפשותיכם אדרוש והוא המית את עצמו:

That is, again: אע"פ שלא יש לחוש ולא נאמר על זה תמים תהיה

Which can be translated as "even though it is not so, there is to be be heedful, and there is not in it a [violation] of "You shall be simple with [Hashem your God]."

The [Perush Kadmon](https://www.sefaria.org/Perush_Kadmon_on_Sefer_Chasidim.477.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) on that siman notes a variant text here which makes it match a bit more to the English quote:

> נ"א והרבה כיוצא באלה. אע"פ שלא לנחש יש לחוש ולא נאמר כו' כתיב מי האיש ירא השם וגו'. ר"ל מי שהוא האיש ירא השם הוא יורנו כדרך הישר והנכון שראוי לבחור ולא יעסוק בהנ"ל:

> "An alternate version: 'And many like this. Even though one should not **practice divination**, there is here to be heedful, and we do not say..."

This is an accurate tracing of the development of the quote. I am not convinced, though, that the English version (especially as it is taken) does justice to the original. Still, in context, the teacher who was worried about the black cat, is someone parallel to the Sefer Chassidim who says that we shouldn't practice divination/omens (to act or not to act), yet one should still be heedful and this is not a violation of Tamim Tihyeh (to not have two brothers marry two sisters, or a man and his son marrying women with the same name, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Pesachim 110b says something similar -

כְּלָלָא דְמִילְּתָא כׇּל דְּקָפֵיד קָפְדִי בַּהֲדֵיהּ וּדְלָא קָפֵיד לָא קָפְדִי בַּהֲדֵיהּ וּמִיהוּ לְמֵיחַשׁ מִיבְּעֵי. 'The general rule is that anyone who is particular about them (drinking in pairs), the demons are particular with him, and anyone who is not particular, the demons are not particular with him.

R Moshe Feinstein says similar regarding the ayin hara - Igros Moshe Even Ha'Ezer 3:26.

בענין עין הרע ודאי יש לחוש אבל אין להקפיד הרבה כי בדברים כאלו הכלל מאן דלא קפיד לא קפדינן בהדיה

Comment: Thank you ZakE and welcome to Mi Yodeya. This doesn't answer the question, but would make a very interesting comment!